# Java sub string - need to get part of the string based on some text

Tags: java, string

Need to get some part of the java string, example below:

String lstr = "/nw-resource-pool:resource-pools/numeric-pools[name='testpool'][scope='1.1.1.1-component-id-cab-1-slot-1-card-1-pxc-1-1-3-dir']/used-resources[value='346']";

would like to fetch after scope=' text...

**o/p**: 1.1.1.1-component-id-cab-1-slot-1-card-1-pxc-1-1-3-dir

tried below, any better approach

```
    int rsrc = lstr.lastIndexOf("/");

    lstr = lstr.substring(0,rsrc);

    String[] lsplit = lstr.split("scope='");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String#replaceAll` for a one-liner solution:

```java
String lstr = "/nw-resource-pool:resource-pools/numeric-pools[name='testpool'][scope='1.1.1.1-component-id-cab-1-slot-1-card-1-pxc-1-1-3-dir']/used-resources[value='346']";
String scope = lstr.replaceAll(".*\\[scope='(.*?)'\\].*", "$1");
System.out.println(scope);
```

This prints:

```
1.1.1.1-component-id-cab-1-slot-1-card-1-pxc-1-1-3-dir
```